# Angular 2+ : Is it possible to run component lifecycle hooks outside the component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component, that I render dynamically with

```
const component = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<BaseComponent(CommonPopupComponent).create(this.injector);
component.instance.data = data;
return component.location.nativeElement;
```

And it's not possible to use lifecycle hooks inside myComponent because it extends another class.

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-common-popup',
      templateUrl: './common-popup.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./common-popup.component.scss'],
     changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush })
export class CommonPopupComponent extends BasePopupComponent implements OnInit { ... }
```

But I need to call a fucntion when CommonPopupComponent is being initialized (in ngOnInit to be exact).
Is there any opportunity to call a function, which belongs to CommonPopupComponent outside it at the moment when CommonPopupComponent is being initialized?

Currently I call my function inside CommonPopupComponent's constructor, but I believe, there's a better way to call it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-common-popup',
      templateUrl: './common-popup.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./common-popup.component.scss'],
     changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush })
export class CommonPopupComponent extends BasePopupComponent implements OnInit {
    override onInit(): void {
      super.ngOnInit();
      ... you code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can implement `ngOnInit` inside `CommonPopupComponent` and trigger your function there.

```
ngOnInit() {
super.ngOnInit();
// call your function here
this.yourFunction();
}
```